# How to search a json file C#?

Tags: c#, json

So I have a json file which I am trying to make a method where you input the ID(first ID is 2, second is 6, etc), and it returns the name in C#. Thanks!

Im using Newtonsoft.json library

```
 {
"2": {
"name": "Cannonball",
"store": 5
},
"6": {
"name": "Cannon base",
"store": 187500
},
"8": {
"name": "Cannon stand",
"store": 187500
}
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried with so far? Put in a [mcve] of your code if your have one, otherwise try yourself first. [So] is not a free online code provider service.

Comment: serialize them into object list then Where()

Comment: You mean _deserialize_ them, right? (Couldn't tag you, so...)

Answer (score 1):

The Newtonsoft library doesn't have a search api. You'll have to deserialize the json first, then search through the resulting objects. There are about a million different ways you can do that (JObjects, Dictionaries, Linq...). Below is one:

```
class Program
{
    internal class ParsedObject
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Store;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""2"": 
            {
                ""name"": ""Cannonball"",
                ""store"": 5
            },
            ""6"": 
            {
                ""name"": ""Cannon base"",
                ""store"": 187500
            },
            ""8"": 
            {
                ""name"": ""Cannon stand"",
                ""store"": 187500
            }
        }";

        var jsonDeserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ParsedObject>>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonDeserialized["2"].Name);

    }
}
```